# Get ListView item ID and launch method on items listitem's label Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin.forms, binding

I have a `ListView` that has label and image in a `ViewCell`.

I already have `ListView`'s `SelectedItem` Binding set to get the item's ID and use it for one method if user selects the image part of the item.

I would like to have another method launched when the user taps the label of the item, something like this:

```
<TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
```

Should I follow the same procedure to get the ID as I do in `SelectedItem`?

`SelectedItem` Binding I do like so:

```
async void ShowDetails(int selectedItemID)
{
    await _navigation.PushAsync(new DetailsPage(selectedItemID));
}

Items _selectedItem;
public Items SelectedItem
{
    get => _selectedItem;
    set
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
            ShowDetails(value.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

In few words I want the user to get items ID and launch one method when clicked on a label, and get items ID and launch another method when clicked on an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `CommandParameter` in your `TapGestureRecogniser`. If you don't know how to deal with the `CommandParameter`, please read through the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/commanding#using-command-parameters) or have a look at this [article](https://blog.xamarin.com/simplifying-events-with-commanding/).

I would assume you could do something like this:

```
<TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" 
                      CommandParameter="{Binding .}" 
                      NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
```

The dot in the `{Binding .}`, means that the parent `BindingContext` will be passed through to the `CommandParameter`.

NOTE: The `.` in the `{Binding .}` is optional, you could just write `{Binding}` and it should also work

**EDIT**: *How to handle `CommandParameter` in code*

There's plenty examples online, you could have a look at these [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/commanding#asynchronous-commanding-for-navigation-menus) to get an idea. In your case the parameter will be an `int`, so the code could look something like this:

```
SomeCommand = new Command<int>((int id) =>
{
    // add command handler code here
});
```

Comment: Will this actually get access to corresponding item so I can get Item's ID?(eg getting object to pass ID further in the method)

Comment: I am not really sure how to write a Command so the corresponding Item Id is passed to the executed method.

Comment: I edited my answer with a sample for handling the command in code

Comment: I didn't even have to put Id in command. Command parameter was all I needed. Thanks

Comment: It didn't work at first because I had to set the source binding to the page. Before that the method didn't even kick-off